# Pandas unlist one dataframe column in chain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tolist

I would like to unlist one Pandas dataframe column into multiple columns in a chain. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns), but ideally in a chain to help readability as there are more steps afterwards. Here is my example, which doesn't work.

```
d1 = {
    'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG']],
    'bal':[5,7,8]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

#unlist teams column in chain
res=(df2
   .pd.DataFrame(df2['teams'].to_list(), columns=['team1','team2'])
   .assign(bal2=lambda x: x['bal']*2)
)

#final result like this
d3 = {
    'team1': ['SF','SF','SF'],
    'team2': ['NYG','NYG','NYG'],
    'bal':[5,7,8],
    'bal2':[10,14,16]
}

df4 = pd.DataFrame(d3)
```

Comment: @Mayank Porwal linked dupe is in question, so I think not dupe.

Comment: @jezrael Got it. Reopened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column and converting to `DataFrame` then is possible add [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for append all another columns:

```
res= (pd.DataFrame(df2.pop('teams').to_list(), columns=['team1','team2'], index=df2.index)
        .join(df2)
        .assign(bal2 = lambda x: x['bal']*2))

print (res)
  team1 team2  bal  bal2
0    SF   NYG    5    10
1    SF   NYG    7    14
2    SF   NYG    8    16
```

Comment: can I do this in a chain? for example in the next line multiply bal by 2 using lambda

Comment: @Zeus - Not sure if understand what is chain. Can you be more specific?

Comment: In R I use %>% in python I think . is used to link functions

Comment: pseudo code is to unlist teams and then in next line multiply bal by 2

Comment: ``res=(df2
   .pd.DataFrame(df2['teams'].to_list(), columns=['team1','team2'])
   .assign('bal2' lambda x: x['bal']*2)
)``

Comment: @Zeus - added to answer.